# Folder permissions: Can anyone explain wht I cannot write to this file without sudo

Tags: permissions

I am having a huge amount of trouble with permissions in /var/www

Can anyone explain why I cannot write here ? All permission look correct to

[image]

Any help would be great.

Comment: also check /var/www :)

Comment: You haven't actually showns us the permissions for /var/www, just the files in /var/www/cms  All we can draw from this information, is you should be able to edit one of those files based on your group membership.  Nothing about creating new files in /var/www, or /var/www/cms  what is the output of 'ls -al'  ?

Comment: Vote to close - the system is not running Ubuntu, but rather Raspbian which is a Debian derivative.

Answer (score 1):

If you do `ls -al` you will most likely get this:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 11 www-data www-data  4096 ene 19 22:42 .
drwxr-xr-x. 23 www-data www-data  4096 ene 20 12:09 ..
```

This says that no one but www-data user can write in the directory. You need to modify the directory itself permissions to be allowed to create file in the directory:

```
sudo chmod g+w /var/www
```

And voila.